# Social meta tags when several articles on same page

Tags: share, social-networking, meta-tags, article

This is my first attempt with social share buttons on a classic HTML website (not a CMS).

I understand that social meta tags are now the way to go as you have more control on what you are sharing (you can have more control on the title, the picture, the description, the content type etc..).

What I don't get is **how to share a specific article only** when you have ten articles displayed on the same page.
All the tutorials I read about sharing buttons are dedicated to a whole web page but I would like to share a specific section of the page per button, not the whole page (one page = 10 articles = 10 share buttons).
How would I achieve that?

Thank you.

(Bonus question: are social meta tags shared by FB, twitter and linkedin or are they only dedicated to FB?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you are still struggling with this, but I've just been thinking about a similar-but-different problem, with a one-page site where the content is swapped out dynamically so that it is not possible to change the og: tags in the header.

The solution requires generating individual pages for each specific article that have their own  with dedicated og: tags. Then in your page which lists 10 articles, each one has a share button where the link points to the specific article page, e.g. `<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://yoursite.com/article1.html">`.

When some clicks the share button, facebook will crawl the target url for og: tags, not the page you are currently on.

In your case the solution is pretty straightforward, as you presumably have individual pages for the articles already. Mine is slightly trickier because I have to generate extra pages which won't be navigated to from my site but exist for facebook to crawl (and to display the right content when people arrive via the social shares).

Comment: I was exactly in your situation: the articles were to short to benefit from a dedicated page. This is why I had to groupe them. Anyway, having found no viable solution I did exactly what you suggest: I created individual pages for each article which are not accessible to the users within the website and only serve the FB purpose. It's not ideal but it works just fine. I had to tweak the design of those pages though in order for them to look less...empty. Some extra work indeed but now it's done and I'm ok with it. Thanks for your input! Let's call it a viable answer (the only one I know of).

Comment: I figured you must have had individual pages for the articles, because, if not, what were you going to display? The list of 10 articles? In which case you could have just shared the list page. But as I write this I realise you would have wanted different titles, descriptions, images etc for each article. Would be nice if you were able to use anchor tags on the same page for separate shares...